what owner:group should I set my lampp(apache and mysql) folder, so a non sudoer user can execute it without sudo command?
I installed the lampp suite via a sudoer user, but I need to be able to use it through another user that isn't in the sudoers file. Is it possible?

Yes I did that by changing my lampp's ownership :
sudo chown -R sudo1:sudo2 /opt/lampp 

(change the 'opt/lampp' to your lampp directories if you install in other directories, change 'sudo1' to your old sudo, change 'sudo2' to your new sudo)
Then give permission for new sudo
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp

and then open home/.bashrc , add lampp's PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin

(again, if not in opt/, change the /opt/lampp/bin to your lampp directory)
then restart lampp...
sorry for my poor english~
